# How do I set up classes in a Lein project?

Tags: java, class, clojure

I ran `lein new app hm`, then in `hm/src/hm` edited `core.clj` to be:

```
(ns hm.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:use [hm.hashmap]))

(defn -main []
  (def j (new hm.hashmap))
  (-add j "foo" "bar")
  (println j))
```

and `hashmap.clj` to be:

```
(ns hm.hashmap
  (:gen-class
   :methods [[hashmap [] java.util.HashMap]
             [add [String String]]]))

(defn -hashmap []
  (def h (new java.util.HashMap))
  h)

(defn -add [this key value]
  (. this put key value)
  this)
```

The goal is to make a wrapper around the HashMap so I can understand Clojure and how it ties with Java. I'm fairly new to Clojure. However, when I compile this, I get a lot of ClassNotFoundException in `hashmap.clj`. How can I make this work?

Comment: What class is not found?

Comment: @JeremyHeiler `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang., compiling:(hm/hashmap.clj:1:1)`

Comment: This is not a normal way to do things in Clojure, I would compare it to learning C by starting with inline assembly blocks - while clojure objects become classes and methods in the jvm, working in terms of classes and methods in Clojure (except interop where you are pulling in a java class) is a rare and specialized thing. Instead of starting with generating java Classes, I would start with Clojure functions that use java classes, and build up from there.

Comment: @noisesmith Thank you for the advice! Where can I start with that?

Comment: http://www.4clojure.com/ and https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans are good interactive introductions to clojure. The O'Reilly Clojure Programming book (by Chas Emerick) and The Joy of Clojure also great resources, with comprehensive information on Java interop. The kind of interop you are attempting here is pretty much only needed if you are writing Java code that you want to be able to call Clojure code from - the other way around is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is a direct answer to your question. I don't recommend that you learn Clojure this way.*

---

You need to compile your classes before you can run them. In your project.clj add this to the map:

```
:aot [hm.hashmap]
```

Then you need to run `lein compile` in order to compile the classes. You should see output saying the `hm.hashmap` class was compiled. After that run `lein run` to invoke the "main "function in `hm.core`.

I removed the `:methods` part of your gen-class because you're already defining them below, and that was causing the weird `java.lang.,` error. You're going to run into other errors, but this should be enough to get you passed this issue.

Comment: Alright, I added the `aot` line and compiled, but in `lein run` I get: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: put for class hm.hashmap`. Now I understand this is the wrong way to learn Clojure, so could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @tekknolagi Like he said, "you're going to run into other errors". For the shortest edit to make this run pretty much as is, see my answer. For general resources on Clojure see [the Clojure tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/clojure/info).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some other issues, but the immediate problem here is that the signature of `add` is incomplete. Your `add` returns `this`, a `hm.hashmap`.

To fix, change the signature to return an `Object`, or, with additional edit, a `java.util.HashMap`. If you want this to work as otherwise written, you'll also need to extend rather than encapsulate.

```
(ns hm.hashmap
  (:gen-class
   :extends java.util.HashMap
   :methods [[add [String String] java.util.HashMap]]))
```

Finally change `-main` in `core.clj` to call the method using `.add` instead of trying to access the private `-add`.

```
...
(.add j "foo" "bar")
...
```

Then

```
lein clean
lein compile hm.core hm.hashmap
lein run
```

should print

```
#<hashmap {foo=bar}>
```

Note that you cannot, as far as I know, specify returning an `hm.hashmap` in the signature due to the timing of the symbol resolution. See [GC Issue 81: compile gen-class fail when class returns self](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-84).

Comment: @tekknolagi See edit, you'll also need to change `-add` to `.add` in `core.clj` to use the method (versus trying to access the private function).

Comment: @tekknolagi Eh, and `:extends java.util.HashMap`. Funny how many edits I immediately made to the original without thinking about it. Keep in mind you'll discover much better ways to do what I ultimately edited you into in Clojure, as others have hinted.